# Postfix before queue filter

Tags: postfix-mta

I write my own classification email software, now i want to connect it with postfix.

To redirect the mail, is it enough to change these two parameters in the master.cf file and add some code in my filter to listening port 10025?

```
   # Before-filter SMTP server. Receive mail from the network and
   # pass it to the content filter on localhost port 10025.
   #
   smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       20      smtpd
       -o smtpd_proxy_filter=127.0.0.1:10025  #CHANGE NR 1
       -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=10
       # Postfix 2.7 and later performance feature.
       # -o smtpd_proxy_options=speed_adjust
   #
   # After-filter SMTP server. Receive mail from the content filter
   # on localhost port 10026. #CHANGE NR 2
   #
   127.0.0.1:10026 inet n  -       n       -        -      smtpd
       -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, this is how it works in principle. The snippet from the [official postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html) is more involved, though.

However, your mail filter software has to speak SMTP the way Postfix expects it (cf. also the linked document). For example, you have to stream the message (i.e. proxy it, hence the name) in case you want to accept it.

An alternative way to implement before-queue filtering is to user the [Milter protocol/API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milter), which [postfix also supports](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html).